# How to set dynamic memory growth on TF 2.1?

Tags: tensorflow, memory, gpu, tf.keras

With previous versions of tensorflow+keras I was able to set an 'allow_growth' option and view realtime memory usage with nvidia-smi.  Otherwise it will all gett allocated immediately by the process.  Now, using tf.keras in tensorflow 2.1 I can't find a way to do this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth

Comment: I will try this and report back, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case you have several GPUs, you will allow memory growth only for the first GPU.

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

If you want to do it for all GPUs you need to set it for every instance.

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
for gpu_instance in physical_devices: 
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu_instance, True)
```

Comment: Is there a driver-level solution for this, that doesn't depend on the framework? Basically say - prevent all CUDA apps from hogging all GPU memory by default?

Comment: You may be able to get this behaviour by setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES. I've not tested this with other apps/frameworks but I believe it should work. https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/

Comment: no, that just hides a GPU completely from the code. I want the code to not allocate memory greedily on the GPU, that's all.

Comment: Oh I see, unfortunately I'm doubtful anything like that exists.

Comment: I'm seeing that even without setting this, TF2 doesn't take up all the memory anyway. So maybe this is not needed?